# Not able to fetch value of column having double quotes in its value

Tags: mysql

I am facing a problem in mysql query. I have a column named description and for this column there are a lots of records having double quotes in value and there are more then  9K records in table so i can't remove double quotes

For Example :

```
id    ======>1

name =====> Amy

Description ======>  This is Amy"s description
```

but i am not able to fetch record with query :

```
SELECT * From table;
```

Every time i was returned with a empty result

Can anyone help me to find out a solution.

Comment: Without a WHERE you should get all the data,quotes or no quotes.Are you are that`s the real query?

Comment: i am not using any where clause in query but still i am not able to get any records

Comment: The quotes are not the problem if you're fetching all the records, may be it is taking time and your connection times out. Try to get 1 or 2 rows (use limit).

Comment: No, I am using limit. but if there is "" in value and limit is 10 then also its returning empty value